# How to get Alternative row colours using a gridControl component

Tags: java, swing, gridview, awt, gridcontrol

I'm currently working on redoing the `GUI` of a project which uses the component `GridControl` which is an extension of gridView, found here:

http://techpubs.borland.com/books/jbuilder/jbuilder2/jbuilder/reference/borland.jbcl.control.GridControl.html

I'm not allowed to change the components used so I have to find a way to do this with `gridControl`, however I'm relatively new at programming, so don't really know what I'm doing.  I've been asked to get the alternative rows of the table to be grey. I can't find a specific function of the component which caters for this like `JTabel` seems to have so I was hoping that someone would be able to help. The only one which seems related is `.setBackground` which seems to only affect the full table.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [THIS](http://oswing.sourceforge.net/gui2.html) link. It has a mention of this function:

**`public Color getBackgroundColor(..):`**`callback method automatically invoked by the grid to retrieve the background color for each grid's cell. A programmer can override this method to specify distinct colors for grid's cells.
If the method is not overridden, then rows are colored alternatively with two different colors: one color is defined through ClientSettings.GRID_CELL_BACKGROUND attribute and the other color is slightly different from the first one, defined through getDeltaColor() method.`

now, the defaule colour values for `ClientSettings.GRID_CELL_BACKGROUND` is rgb (238,238,238) which is **grey**, and for `deltaColor` is rgb (235,235,235) also **grey**.

so, the cells should all be grey, unless there's been an `override` for the function `public Color getBackgroundColor(..)`, something like this:

```
public Color getBackgroundColor(int row,String attributedName,Object value) {
    return new Color(255,255,255); /*for all cells to be White*/
}
```

In order to make alternate rows grey (assuming the other color white) find the `override` of the above method and change its body to get your required colours, for eg:

```
public Color getBackgroundColor(int row,String attributedName,Object value) {
    if (row%2==0)
         return new Color(255,255,255); /*sets White background for even rows*/
    else
    return new Color(238,238,238); /*sets Grey background for odd rows*/
}
```

---

`I'm relatively new at programming, so don't really know what I'm doing`  hmm.. there are a lot of help/examples available online. you need to learn to search intelligently and follow it up with some background theory to learn on your own.. and you'll survive (for now).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'll work on getting this in as you've described. I've had a brief look and haven't been able to find the override but it may just be that it's my own background function conflicting

Yes.. I have found I've been struggling with finding useful info when searching for help and I need to look at how I'm searching to narrow it down to be more accurate. My own lacking background theory is the biggest factor I'm sure. When I said relatively new, it's now been a week and a half since I started. However I'm studying and working hard, but again, thanks for your help.